# getting doubleclick position from CListCtrl in dialog's OnNotify

Tags: mfc, windows-10, visual-studio-2019, clistctrl

I have a dialog window (with `CDialogEx` based class) containing a single list control (report view, with `CListCtrl` attached as a control variable). I want to check which line of the displayed list was double clicked.

I thought it will be just a matter of adding `OnNotify` and converting the double click coordinates to the line number:

```cpp
BOOL MyDialog::OnNotify(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    if (((NMMOUSE *)lParam)->hdr.idFrom == IDC_MYLIST &&
        ((NMMOUSE *)lParam)->hdr.code == NM_DBLCLK)
    {
        CPoint cp(((LPNMMOUSE)lParam)->pt);
        int iLine = myListCtrl.HitText(cp);
```

It partially works: I am correctly catching doubleclick notifications coming from the control. What doesn't work though is I don't get correct double click coordinates. cp contains some numbers as coordinates, but they are wrong. x is always 0, and y is what x should be.

Any ideas where I am going wrong and what should I do? With some digging it looks like `lParam` points to some structure containing the coordinates, but it is not `NMMOUSE` as I expected, and I can't find any information about what other structure it could be.

Comment: Maybe you have to do a transform,. like `ScreenToClient` etc. Re-confirm what type of coordinates you are receiving and use the correct transformation as needed.

Comment: AndrewTruckle no, it was not a matter of screen/client coordinates, that I checked; IInspectable below gave the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is deep into undefined behavior from the get-go: The only guarantee you get from the system when receiving a `WM_NOTIFY` message is that `lParam` points to an [`NMHDR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/richedit/ns-richedit-nmhdr) structure. That's a piece of generic information provided to direct subsequent processing.

Consequently, the only safe unconditional cast in an [`OnNotify`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#onnotify) override is from `LPARAM` into `NMHDR const*`, so let's just do that to keep our sanity:

```cpp
BOOL MyDialog::OnNotify(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    NMHDR const& hdr = *reinterpret_cast<NMHDR const*>(lParam);
    if (hdr.idFrom != IDC_MYLIST || hdr.code != NM_DBLCLK)
        return false;
    // ...
```

Once the preconditions have been established, it's safe to move on. At this point we know that the origin passed our filter (`IDC_MYLIST`), and that the notification is an [`NM_DBLCLK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/nm-dblclk-list-view), which passes additional information by way of a pointer to an [`NMITEMACTIVATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-nmitemactivate) structure.

The following takes advantage of that additional knowledge, and produces a `CPoint` holding the double-click position:

```cpp
    // ...
    NMITEMACTIVATE const& info = *reinterpret_cast<NMITEMACTIVATE const*>(lParam);
    CPoint const cp = CPoint(info.ptAction);
    // ...
```

Comment: thanks, NMITEMACTIVATE is exactly what I couldn't find; and you are perfectly right about the NMHDR - that's what I started with, just lost the track of changes several iterations later